# Number of automatas in single output automaton of n inputs

Tags: combinatorics, automata

In John von Neumann's [lecture](https://static.ias.edu/pitp/archive/2012files/Probabilistic_Logics.pdf) titled **Probabilistic Logics and the Synthesis of Reliable Organisms From Unreliable Components** there is a defination 1 of single output automaton on page 3. And it is written that number of such automation is $2^{(2n)}$. I have tried to figure out how he got this number but failed. Can someone show how to reach this number ?

[image]

Comment: I'm also stumped by it.  It appears to me that the correct value should be $2^{2^n}$, which is the number of functions $\mathcal{P}([n]) \to \{0,1\}$, or $2^{2^n - 2}$ if you exclude "all" and "none". This is compounded further by the fact that he later (p.5) enumerates single-input single-output automata as two types: "live" and "grounded", and from the details there it appears the "all" category is not truly excluded.

I'm guessing this is a typo and that the true value should be $2^{2^n-1}$ (excluding only "none"), but defer to someone who knows automata better.

Comment: To elaborate on the last point, I am interpreting excluding "all" or "none" to mean that $\varnothing \mapsto 0$ and $[n]\mapsto 1$ for all automata.  But the first condition appears to be broken when a "live" single-input automaton takes $\{1\}\mapsto 1$, and a "grounded" automaton has $\{1\}\mapsto 0$.

Comment: Another error: The author mixes up "latter" and "former" when defining "live" and "grounded".  This lends credence to the fact that you may have found a typo.  Unfortunately I was not able to find an errata file for this text.